# How to obtain or calculate the average load of a specified CPU on a Linux system with multiple CPUs?

Tags: linux, cpu, loading

I tried command such as

- top
- iostat
- uptime
- lscpu

and file such as

- /proc/loadavg
- /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuX

. All of above, only show the global average loading. Then ,I check the 'https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/cpu-load.html' page. But no use!

Please advise how I can do.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.  **load average** on Linux (and other Unix systems) is a measure for the entire system over time, looking at the last 1, 5 and 15 minutes.  To ask about "load average" for a single CPU is like asking how many Kilometers one wheel of a car has done.  What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Assuming that the total load of the car is constantly changing, the contribution of each tire also changes. At each moment, the load factor of the tire is the current load divided by the maximum load of the tire, the average load of each tire , Is the average value of multiple sampling values of tire load rate.

Comment: Current load over which period of time, though, as it's a rolling average with three different sampling rates?